# How can i use plugins options in javascript instanciation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a plugin on fixed nav using javascript/jQuery. Now the problem is to using defaults value. My questions are:

1. How can I use defaults through instantiation?
2. What is the easiest way to get the default values ?

```js
;(function($){
    'use strict'
    $.fn.retrivenav = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            menuTransform : 'primary',
            speed : '1000',
            responsive : true
        },
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var R = function(){
            this.w = $(window).width();
            this.t = $('.retrivenav').offset().top;
        } 
        var r = new R();

        r.prototype.fixednav = function() {
            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this` keyword inside function

```
;(function($){

'use strict'
    $.fn.retrivenav = function(options){
        this.defaults = {

            menuTransform : 'primary',
            speed : '1000',
            responsive : true

        };

        var options = $.extend(this.defaults, options);

        var R = function(){
            this.w = $(window).width();
            this.t = $('.retrivenav').offset().top;
        } 

        var r = new R();


        r.prototype.fixednav = function(){
            $(window).on('scroll', function(){

            });
        }
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

so you can use like this

```
var retrivenavObj = $('selector').retrivenav();
retrivenavObj.defaults;
```

Comment: if you want each instance to have its own default values then you have to assign it to current object(this) so that you can access/alter using the same object

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
//Plugin definition
$.fn.pluginName = function(options) {   
    return this.each(function() {

        var that = $(this); 

        //Get defaults
        var def = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluginName.defaults, options);
            var optionOne = def.optionOne;
            var optionTwo = def.optionTwo;

        // Here you can use optionOne, optionTwo or whatever default variable you set

    });
};

//Defaults
$.fn.tableFix.defaults = {
    optionOne: true,    
    optionTwo: false
};

})(jQuery, window, document)
```

Then, when you instantiate:

**Defaul options**

```
$('#affected-table').tableFix();
```

The plugin will get the default options (optionOne: true, optionTwo: false)

**Change an option**

```
var options = {
    optionOne: false
}
$('element_to_affect').pluginName(options);
```

The optionOne will now be overwritten and become 'false', but optionTwo will remain false

**For more information on plugin development**

take a look [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638948/extremely-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial)

Comment: But i need to use the options values is my code.Such as if i want to use optionone value in my plugin code??

Comment: If you define an option object and pass these options when you instantiate the plugin, these options will overwrite the default options and you can use them as well (Check my answer in "Change an option")

Comment: Ops no .I am not asking that . What i am asking is about in plugin.Such as i can get value of speed option like this:
       `defaults.speed`

The question is how can i use it in

        `var R = function(){
            this.w = $(window).width();
            this.t = $('.retrivenav').offset().top;
        }`
OR in the instansiation of it.